# Restricted mean estimator, why so different from mean of observation time?

Tags: survival, interpretation

I am very intrigued regarding the restricted mean in time to event analyses.

I understood it's an estimate of the time to event in a population considering that some people experienced it and some other not.
But when I used it with real data I found some results that made me think I didn't understand it's meaning at all.

I have a dataset of people of which a subset experienced a certain kind of events. For each event, I want to estimate the event free time for these people, therefore I created some variables which record the time to events for the affected subset of people and the total observation time for the rest.

When I estimated the restricted mean (using survfit on R) on these variables, I found that this value is way different from the classical mean. In facts, the restricted mean is much bigger:

```
Restricted mean vs Normal mean

- 13.8 ± 1.04 vs 4.76 ± 4.65
- 7.99 ± 1.33 vs 3.19 ± 3.34
- 18.3 ± 0.83" vs 4.48 ± 4.71
```

It is normal for the estimates to be so different? Am I missing something in the interpretation, or is it a error in my code?

Comment: Can you please explain the new tag restricted-mean? Or better, propose a tag wiki for it?

Comment: In my question I in facts ask more information regarding the restricted mean. I am by no mean expert on the topic so I am not the right person to create a wiki about it. I added the tag because it was missing.